# A problem with "Returns to Scale"

Tags: production-function

Suppose that $Y\subset R^3$ is a production set satisfying the free disposal condition: if $y\in Y$ and $y'\leq y$ then $y'\in Y.$ Suppose the technology of production uses good 1 and good 2 as inputs to produce good 3.

Define the set $\bar{Y}=\{(-z_2,q):(-\bar{z}_1,-z_2,q)\in Y\}\subset R^2$ as the production possibilities available when the use of the first good is fixed at level $\bar{z}_1$. How do i show that if $Y$ exhibits constant returns to scale, the $\bar{Y}$ exhibits nonincreasing returns to scale?

In addition, is it possible for $Y$ to be such that $\bar{Y}$ also exhibits CRTS no matter at what level $z_1$ is fixed?

Here is my attempt. If $Y$ is CRTS, then $(-z_1,-z_2,q)\in Y$ and $(-tz_1,-tz_2,tq)\in Y$. Let $t\in (0,1)$. But in this case, $z_1$ is fixed, so how do I proceed? I am unsure of how to use the "free disposal" condition.

Comment: Have you tried directly applying the definitions to either of your questions? Can you edit in your attempt so that we can see where you get stuck?

Comment: Also have you considered accepting [these](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56909/how-can-i-show-that-the-optimal-savings-are-0-for-all-time-periods) [answers](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56951/why-is-the-budget-correspondence-lower-hemicontinuous) to your older questions?

Comment: @Giskard Hi - I have accepted answers and added my attempt. Thank you!

Comment: $(-\bar{z}_1,-tz_2,tq)\leq(-t\bar{z}_1,-tz_2,tq)$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $Y$ has constant returns to scale, which means that if for all $t > 0$
$$
(-z_1, -z_2, q) \in Y \to (-tz_1, -tz_2, tq) \in Y
$$
We want to show that $\overline{Y}$ has non-increasing returns to scale, which means that for all $t \in (0,1]$
$$
(-z_2,  q) \in \overline{Y} \to (-tz_2, tq) \in \overline{Y},
$$

Fix $z_1$ at $\bar z_1$.
Then for $t \in (0,1]$ as $\bar z_1 \ge t z_1$, we have:
$$
(-t\bar z_1, -t z_2, ty) \ge (-\bar z_1, -tz_2, ty).
$$
So by free disposal:
$$
(-t \bar z_1, -t z_2, ty) \in Y \to (-\bar z_1 - t z_2, t y) \in Y \tag{1}
$$
So for all $t \in (0,1]$
$$
\begin{align*}
&(-z_2, y) \in \overline{Y},\\
\leftrightarrow &(-\bar z_1, -z_2, y) \in Y,\\
\to &(-t\bar z_1, -tz_2, ty) \in Y,\\
\to &(-\bar z_1, -tz_2, t y) \in Y,\qquad \tag{ from (1)}\\
\leftrightarrow &(-tz_2, ty) \in \overline{Y}.
\end{align*}
$$